# Getting possible null reference argument warning with Xunit.assert.source 2.4.2

Tags: c#, xunit

When I use `xunit.assert.source` I get a possible null warning (CS6804) for `Assert.NotNull`

```
[Fact]
public void DoTest()
{
   int? value = null;

   Assert.NotNull(value); // <-- This line
   int foo = value.Value;
}
```

This is my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.assert.source" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.core" Version="2.4.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If I use `xunit.assert` instead of `xunit.assert.source`, I do not have this problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this, so I can use `xunit.assert.source`?

Comment: Yeah, xunit source code uses a number of preprocessor symbols. If you look at the declaration of Assert.NotNull, you'll notice that you will only get the declaration `public static void NotNull([NotNull] object? @object)` if `XUNIT_NULLABLE` is defined, otherwise you'll get the declaration `public static void NotNull(object @object)` leading to the warning you got. I don't know if it is documented anywhere what preprocessor symbols are being used in the xunit source code for what purposes, though...

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that `XUNIT_NULLABLE`. I have tried adding `#define XUNIT_NULLABLE` but that does not help.

But while writing this I wanted to try everything, and found a solution. Added below.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Symbols defined with `#define` are scoped to the file in which the `#define` symbol is being declared. No surprise that `#define XUNIT_NULLABLE` won't work unless you plonk it right into the source file with the Assert.NotNull declaration :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE; XUNIT_NULLABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE; XUNIT_NULLABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.assert.source" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.core" Version="2.4.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

to

```
<Nullable>disable</Nullable>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. But if I then change my test to this:

[Fact]
public void DoTest()
{
   object? value = null;

   Assert.NotNull(value);
   object foo = value;
}

Then I'm back to square one.